# How to manipulate the cal command question

Tags: bash, pipe, cal

I'm stuck on a question on my homework and can't figure the right options and pipes to use of cal or ncal.
The question is the following:

Write a command line to find the number of Monday(s) that fall(s) on the first of the month in a given year. The result must be a displayed number
on the screen.

By changing the year in your command line,
check the results obtained for the years :
1947, 1989, and 2021

CONSTRAINTS

- Use a single command with up to 3 pipes
- No use of sed command or the
  awk command.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you've tried so far?

Comment: @AndyDalton I just figure it out, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ncal 2021 | grep '^Mo' | grep -wo 1 | wc -l
```

search for lines containing `Mo` , then only the 'word' `1` then count the number of lines